# stop executing sub reports in ssrs when we have not clicked on toggle to display the sub report

Tags: reporting-services, database-performance, subreports

I have more than 15 sub reports in my ssrs report.Each sub report should be displayed only when we click on some text to toggle.But in the background(SQL Profiler) is running all the sub report datasets along with the main dataset which is resulting in poor performance.I have gone through different procedures suggested in diff blog but did not find the right solution.
Can someone please help me with this.
Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to this documentation, subreports are run at the same time as the main report:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207141.aspx

The "Performance" section of the above documentation (pasted below) makes a good point, but it would require a slight re-design (but end up with better performance!):

**Performance**

When deciding which to use, consider using a data region instead a subreport, particularly if the subreport is not used by multiple reports. Because the report server processes each instance of a subreport as a separate report, performance can be impacted. Data regions provide much of the same functionality and flexibility as subreports, but with better performance. Drillthrough reports have better performance than subreports, too, because they don't retrieve all the data at the same time as the main report.

Comment: Hi Molley ,As mentioned in your comments , if i want to use the data regions (in the form of a table) all the sub report data sets should be used within the main report ? or do u have any specific suggestions in using data regions please share some example.

Comment: Hi Molley,I have gone through the link provided in your comments  and compared my requirement with each of the available options.Unfortunately,Data regions and Drillthrough are not going to solve my problem.Since i have to reuse the sections and i have to display the data in the main report itself.So i will agree with you and concluding this is not possible.If anybody know the solution for this issue,Please share with us.Thanks.